# How to set session not to expire on browser close in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I would like to set the session in codeigniter version 3 not to expire on browser close. session should be retain for ever. Session should be destoryed when the user click the logout button. In previous version codeigniter used variable called "$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;" but now in codeigniter version 3 we dont have that. how to set in config or create custom core controller to extend the session.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
 $config['sess_use_database']   = TRUE;
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
 $config['sess_expiration'] = 60*60*24*180;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
 $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;
  $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
      $config['cookie_prefix']  = '';
   $config['cookie_domain'] = '';
 $config['cookie_path']     = '/';
    $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
   $config['cookie_httponly']   = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that is not related to codeigniter.
you may want to set session lifetime via ini

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600 * 2); //two hours
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 2);
session_start();
```

also have a look here of how to combine it with CG [Codeigniter increase session time out not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751849/codeigniter-increase-session-time-out-not-working)

**Update**
You can set ini variables via [htaccess](https://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess) or [VirtualHost](https://serverfault.com/a/34519)

Comment: I am using dedicated multiple sites are running. so if i set it like this it will get affect

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```

Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.

***Source:*** config.php (~Line 335)